# JavaFX capture screen using Robot

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I am using a transparent `Stage` in JavaFX which contains a `Canvas`.

The user can draw a `rectangle` in the canvas by dragging the mouse.

> When he hits **enter** i am saving the image using:

```
try {
     ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,extension,outputFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();                        
}
```

> To capture the `image` from screen i am using:

```
gc.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // [gc] is the graphicsContext2D of the Canvas

        // Start the Thread
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {

                // Sleep some time
                Thread.sleep(100);

                // Capture the Image
                BufferedImage image;
                int[] rect = calculateRect();
                try {
                    image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3]));
                } catch (AWTException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
```

> **The problem**:

I  don't know when the `JavaFX Thread` will clear the `Canvas` so i am using a `Thread` as you can see above which is waiting **100 milliseconds** and then capture the screen.But it is not working all the times,what i mean is that sometimes the `Canvas` has not been cleared and i get this image(cause `Canvas` has not been cleared yet):

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

> **The question:**

How i know when the `JavaFX` has cleared the `Canvas` so i can capture the screen after that?

Mixing `Swing` with `JavaFX` is not recommended although that's the only way i know to capture screen with Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really hope there's a better way to achieve what you want than this, but the canvas will be cleared the next time a "pulse" is rendered. So one approach would be to start an `AnimationTimer` and wait until the second frame is rendered:

```
gc.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
AnimationTimer waitForFrameRender = new AnimationTimer() {
    private int frameCount = 0 ;
    @Override
    public void handle(long timestamp) {
        frameCount++ ;
        if (frameCount >= 2) {
            stop();
            // now do screen capture...
        }
    }
};
waitForFrameRender.start();
```

Obviously, if you are doing the screen capture in a background thread, you need to also make sure you don't draw back onto the canvas before the capture occurs...

Comment: Thanks it works!.Although what is "the pulse",how i know that "the pulse" will be rendered the second time?Any plans about importing Robot implementation in JavaFX?Finally if you have a better idea it will be nice to hear! Thanks for the answer...

Comment: Through testing,it works only for small rectangles,selecting the whole screen or a large area i have again invalid image with canvas not cleared..

Comment: Pulses are generated at a target rate of 60 per second by the FX toolkit (they maybe less frequent if the work the FX Application Thread needs to do is taking too long). On each pulse, a UI "frame" is rendered, i.e. the parts of the UI that need repainting are repainted. `AnimationTimer.handle(...)` is guaranteed to be called once per frame. So the idea is that you wait until at least one complete frame has been rendered since you called `clearRect()`, by waiting until `handle()` has been called twice. Not sure why it is not working for large canvases...

Comment: Modified it to >=5 and seems to work for all the tests now.

Comment: Yeah, but guessing the number of frames that have to be rendered is barely better than guessing the amount of time that has to pass, as in your original post. Seems this approach isn't really feasible. I'll leave this here until someone comes up with a better solution though.